# Pandas: Join results from extractall

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a dataframe, and I want to extract all occurences of a pattern and then join them as a single string to become a new column of my original dataframe.

Example:

```
original = pd.DataFrame(["bonjour bonjour", "au revoir bonjour", "lala"])


                   0
0    bonjour bonjour
1  au revoir bonjour
2               lala
```

expected result :

```
                   0                 1
0    bonjour bonjour  bonjour, bonjour
1  au revoir bonjour           bonjour
2               lala
```

Where I'm stuck:

```
extracted = original[0].str.extractall("(bonjour)")

               0
  match         
0 0      bonjour
  1      bonjour
1 0      bonjour
```

I can't manage this result, I really don't get how to work with the structure. It seems simple but, depending on how I access it, I don't get what I want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `findall` rather than extract all i.e

```
original['new'] = original[0].str.findall('bonjour').apply(','.join)

          0                  new
0    bonjour bonjour   bonjour, bonjour
1  au revoir bonjour            bonjour
2               lala
```

Comment: It says "TypeError": can only join an iterable

Comment: `original[1] = original[0].str.findall('bonjour').str.join(',')` is much faster and concise.